# How to format datetime field to hours minutes seconds in form view in odoo 15

Tags: datetime, format, odoo-15

I have a datetime field and i want to format it to hours, minutes, seconds in the form view like this:

[image]

Is this posible, and how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can research, we can use this as alternative solution:

Change the field from `Datetime` to `Float`:

```
your_field = fields.Float(string='Your Field')
```

Then, in the form view, add `widget="float_time"`:

```
<field name="your_field " widget="float_time"/>
```

And here's the result:
[image]

With this, there's no popup to show (It's bad, i know).

But as i mentioned before, this solution is just a alternative solution until we find better solution.

Other answers are welcome.

Note for the report view or email view, we can use this: `t-options="{'widget': 'float_time'}"`

Thanks.